# Laravel Migrations gives unusual error

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to create a migration using artisan. The migrations class is created without any problems and I construct the table using the `Schema` class. When I run its. It works all good, but when I try and rollback, It gives an error which I don't understand.

**My Migration Class**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Session extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
            Schema::create('Session', function(Blueprint $table){
                $table->string('id', 50);
                $table->string('email', 100);
                $table->integer('lastActivity');
                $table->primary('id');
            });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
            Schema::dropIfExists('Session');
    }

}
```

**Error message**

> [2014-03-25 14:42:16] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Session' not found' in E:\Documents\Dropbox\Documents\WorkSpace_netBeans\Laravel_Test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php:297

Comment: I would save the data, then delete the database then run migrate:install and then try migrante:refresh it works for me but not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Session` migration class might be in conflict with Laravel's `Session` (Facade), rename it to test.

I just created one here:

```
php artisan migrate:make Session
```

And it conflicted while trying to rollback:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::down() in
```